# Convert time to decimal using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I want to convert the time (min:sec:hs) to decimal. Before the comma are for the seconds and after the comma are for Fractional Seconds. Something like:
**02:10:55 = 130,55** (2*60 + 10) & (.55)

**HTML**

```
<form>
Min: <input type="number" id="min" onkeyup="myFunction()">
Sec: <input type="number" id="sec" onkeyup="myFunction()">
Hon: <input type="number" id="hon" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<p class="result"></p> 
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
var num1 = $("input[id='min']").val(),
num2 = $("input[id='sec']").val(),
num3 = $("input[id='hon']").val(),
result = parseInt(num1) * 60 + parseInt(num2);
$(".result").text(result);
}
</script>
```

Thanks to @Andrew Brooke I solved it with this code:

```
result = parseInt(num1) * 60 + parseInt(num2) + "." + parseInt(num3)
```

Now I have another problem. I want to get the results even If I fill only one fields. Now I get **NaN** if one of the field is empty.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance,

Comment: `result = parseInt(num1) * 60 + parseInt(num2) + "." + parseInt(num3);` ?

Comment: @Andrew Brooke. Thank you  very much:)

Comment: @Andrew Brooke. See please my update. I have another problem (NaN) when one of the field is empty. I want to get always a result (OnkeyUp). Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, you can just concatenate your string with a comma

```
result = parseInt(num1) * 60 + parseInt(num2) + "," + parseInt(num3);
```

For the second problem, an easy solution would be to check if the textboxes are empty, and give `num1, num2, or num3` a value of 0 if so. Like this

```
var num1 = $("input[id='min']").val() != "" ? $("input[id='min']").val() : 0,
    num2 = $("input[id='sec']").val() != "" ? $("input[id='sec']").val() : 0,
    num3 = $("input[id='hon']").val() != "" ? $("input[id='hon']").val() : 0,
...
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but I encounter another problem.
I want the comma only when I have the Fractional Seconds. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, only add the comma if it's not 0. `result = parseInt(num1) * 60 + parseInt(num2);
  if (parseInt(num3) != 0)
    result += "," + parseInt(num3);`

Comment: Thank you very, much You saved my day:)

Answer (score 1):

A more concise way is to use `Number()`, which will return `0` when passed the empty string. As a side note, I would rename your variables to make it more readable, and use `$("#min")` instead of `$("input[id='min']")`

```
var hon = Number($("#hon").val()),
    min = Number($("#min").val()),
    sec = Number($("#sec").val());
```

You also want to convert `sec` to decimal, right? You can do that with `sec / 60`. Thus, you should calculate `result` with:

```
var result = hon + min * 60 + sec / 60;
```